# Generic return type in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, generics

Say that I have the generic clone implementation with C#:

```
public class Parent<T> where T : Parent, new()
{
    public T Clone()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class Child : Parent<Child>{ }
```

This way, using `new Child().Clone()` will return an object of type `Child` instead of parent.

Is there an equivalent solution to javascript?

The most I can think of is using a function pointer like this:

```
var parent = function(){
};
parent.prototype.clonePointer = function(){ return new parent(); };
parent.prototype.clone = function(){
        return this.clonePointer();
    };

var child = function(){

};
child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
child.clonePointer = function(){ return new child(); };
```

Is there better solution than this?

Comment: [*Object.create*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) just returns a new, plain object with its internal `[[Prototype]]` set to the supplied object. Since the constructor wasn't called, the new object doesn't have *clone* and *clonePointer* methods.

Comment: @RobG Well, I just learned about `Object.create` and you are right about that. Will update my question for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set [**`constructor`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) back to its original value, i.e. `Child`, *and* establish inheritance properly:

```
function Child() {
    Parent.call(this);
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype, {
    constructor: {value: Child}
});
// or, instead of passing a property descriptor
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
// (but this makes `constructor` enumerable)
```

a clone method can be as simple as

```
Parent.prototype.clone = function() {
    return new this.constructor();
};
```

See also [Classical inheritance with `Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Comment: Oh you are right, I was totally confused by this setup and the casing if the variable names. Fixed with a complete example... thanks!